# Adding sparkline chart to dynamically populated HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, sparklines

I am trying to add a [sparkline chart](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) at the end of each row of my dynamically populated table. Here is my code:

```
function populateOverallOverview(result){
    var table = document.getElementById("firstTabOverall");

    function addCell(tr, text) {
        var td = tr.insertCell();
        td.textContent = text;
        return td;
    }

    result.forEach(function (item) {
        // sparkline chart here
        var dataSpan = document.createElement('span');
        dataSpan.sparkline(amountData, {
        type: 'bar',
        barColor: '#191919'});

        var row = table.insertRow();
        addCell(row, item.category);
        addCell(row, '$ ' + item.currentMonthAmt.toFixed(2));
        addCell(row, item.topMonthStr + ' ($ ' + item.topAmount.toFixed(2) + ')');
    });

}
```

Sample data for the amountData are [5,6,7,2,0,-4,-2,4]. My HTML table:

```
<table id="firstTabOverall" class="table" style="font-size:13px">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Category <span id="sparkline1"></span></th>
                                            <th>Current Month Revenue</th>
                                            <th>Best Selling Month</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

I am trying to dynamically create the sparkline chart then add to the end of the row. However, I am getting this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dataSpan.sparkline is not a function
```

I not sure how to dynamically create a span with ID, then use that ID to .sparkline. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add same data for `result` and the html you want to output.

Comment: @BrahmaDev Hi I have edited the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var amountData = [5, 6, 7, 2, 0, -4, -2, 4];

    function populateOverallOverview(result) {
        var table = document.getElementById("firstTabOverall");

        function addCell(tr, text) {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.textContent = text;
            return td;
        }

        result.forEach(function(item) {
            var row = table.insertRow();
            addCell(row, item.category);
            addCell(row, '$ ' + item.currentMonthAmt.toFixed(2));
            addCell(row, item.topMonthStr + ' ($ ' + item.topAmount.toFixed(2) + ')');

            var lastCell = addCell(row, ""); //Added blank cell for sparkline

            var dataSpan = $("<span>");
            dataSpan.appendTo(lastCell);
            dataSpan.sparkline(amountData, {
                type: 'bar',
                barColor: '#191919'
            });
        });

    }

    populateOverallOverview([{
        category: "Transportation",
        currentMonthAmt: 1,
        topMonthStr: 1,
        topAmount: 1
    }, {
        category: "Healthcare",
        currentMonthAmt: 1,
        topMonthStr: 1,
        topAmount: 1
    }]);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="firstTabOverall" class="table" style="font-size:13px">
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Current Month Revenue</th>
            <th colspan=2>Best Selling Month</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a good implementation @Brahma Dev , perhaps what i was trying to convery all along +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message does not suggest that span element is created or not, it say's the code is unable to find `sparkline` function, in order to resolve this issue
please ensure that :

1. That you have included `jquery.sparkline.js` in your page i.e. the
   JavaScript file for sparkline is present.
2. Also pay attention to the order in which you have loaded `jquery` and
   `jquery.sparkline.js` , first load `jQuery` and then `sparkline`

Also note that the `jquery selector` always return an array-like `jquery` object,which is different from element returned by `JavaScript createElement()`

What i mean to say is :

```
var dataSpan = document.createElement('span');
dataSpan.sparkline(...)
```

is different from

```
$("#sparkline").sparkline(...)
```

Suggest you retrieve dynamically added element by `jQuery` and then create `sparkline` chart.

Or , after creating the element set ID attribute as follows

```
dataSpan.setAttribute("id", "yourRandomDynamicIdHere");
$("#yourRandomDynamicIdHere").sparkline(...)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi I managed to create a dummy sparkline by hardcoding it: $("#sparkline").sparkline([5,6,7,2,0,-4,-2,4], {
    type: 'bar',
    barColor: '#191919'}); However, when I tried to create it dynamically as the code above, it threw me that error message

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to actually retrieve the ID of dynamically created element?

Comment: Thanks so much for the helps!